# XSLT to recursively reorganize XML Children

Tags: xml, xls

I am trying to parse some data from SurveyMonkey into a usable XML format for an in-house application.  The SurveyMonkey results come out pretty clunky. The questions are sorted by the "Page" of they study they appear on.  The value used to attribute an answer to a a given question is nested within a some child ID type.  Here is a brief example:

```
<root>
...
    <pages>
        <questions>
            <answers>
                <text>John</text>
                <row_id>123456789</row_id>
            </answers>
            <answers>
                <text>Smith</text>
                <row_id>123456790</row_id>
            </answers>
            <answers>
                <text>jsmith@example.com</text>
                <row_id>123456791</row_id>
            </answers>
            <id>987654321</id>
        </questions>
        <questions>
            <answers>
                <choice_id>144018495</choice_id>
            </answers>
            <id>987654322</id>
        </questions>
        <questions>
            <answers>
                <choice_id>489456456</choice_id>
            </answers>
            <answers>
                <choice_id>159489464</choice_id>
            </answers>
            <id>987654323</id>
        </questions>
        <id>48946496849</id>
    </pages>
    <pages>
        <questions>
            <answers>
                <choice_id>144018495</choice_id>
            </answers>
            <id>987654324</id>
        </questions>
        <questions>
            <answers>
                <choice_id>489456456</choice_id>
            </answers>
            <answers>
                <choice_id>159489464</choice_id>
            </answers>
            <id>987654325</id>
        </questions>
        <id>1541561518</id>
    </pages>
....
    <id>8594816548</id>
</root>
```

And what I'm trying to transform it to has a lot of structure and order dependencies. Using {...} to denote values coming from above

```
<DataExchange>
    <Source>XMLIMPORT</Source>
    <EffectData>
        <DataSet>
            <Source>XMLIMPORT</Source> 
            <IDContainer>
                <FlexiID>
                    <key>ID_KEY</key>
                    <value>{/root/id}</value>
                </FlexibleID>
            </IDContainer>
            <MasterData>
                <FirstName>{/root/pages/questions/text where row_id = 123456789}</FirstName>
                <LastName>{/root/pages/questions/text where row_id = 123456790}</LastName>
                <ContactDetails>
                    <Email>{/root/pages/questions/text where row_id = 123456791}</Email>
                    <Phone1>{...}</Phone1>
                    <Phone2>{...}</Phone2>
                </ContactDetails>
            </MasterData>
            <Organization>hardcoded</Organization>
            {if Choice_ID = x in Question y then...}
            <Flags>
                <FromDate>
                    <key>ID_KEY</key>
                    <value>{/root/id}</value>
                </FlexibleID>
            </IDContainer>
            ...
        </DataSet>
    </EffectData>
</DataExchange>
```

You get the gist.  It's ugly with the answers nested in questions nested in pages all out of order.  I just don't now to grab and answer from the 4th Survey Monky page element and put it all the way up in the front .  The XSD for the XML is pretty rigid on order of elements so I have to regorg a lot here.  Can I copy all of the children out then process?  Any help/thoughts/prayers?

-CJW

Comment: Your desired output XML is now _well-formed_. `<IDContainer>` and `<FlexibleID>` need a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve most of what you want with the following template. Just replace your `{...}` with the appropriate `<xsl:value-of select="..." />` expressions.

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <DataExchange>
        <Source>XMLIMPORT</Source>
        <EffectData>
            <DataSet>
                <Source>XMLIMPORT</Source> 
                <IDContainer>
                    <FlexibleID>
                        <key>ID_KEY</key>
                        <value><xsl:value-of select="/root/id" /></value>
                    </FlexibleID>
                </IDContainer>
                <MasterData>
                    <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="/root/pages/questions/answers[row_id='123456789']/text" /></FirstName>
                    <LastName><xsl:value-of select="/root/pages/questions/answers[row_id='123456790']/text" /></LastName>
                    <ContactDetails>
                        <Email><xsl:value-of select="/root/pages/questions/answers[row_id='123456791']/text" /></Email>
                        <Phone1><xsl:value-of select="'Phone1'" /></Phone1>
                        <Phone2><xsl:value-of select="'Phone2'" /></Phone2>
                    </ContactDetails>
                </MasterData>
                <Organization>hardcoded</Organization>
                {if Choice_ID = x in Question y then...}
                <Flags>
                    <FromDate>
                        <key>ID_KEY</key>
                        <value><xsl:value-of select="/root/id" /></value>
                    </FromDate>
                    <!-- </FlexibleID> -->
                </Flags>
                <!-- </IDContainer>  -->
                ...
            </DataSet>
        </EffectData>
    </DataExchange>
</xsl:template>
```

I couldn't implement your `{if Choice_ID = x in Question y then...}` because it is too unspecific.

Comment: Wasn't familiar enough with the syntax you used in the select.  Referencing one element to select another.  Pretty sure that's what I was looking for.  Will give it a go.